How to hide an input field on an Experience cloud page
I have an Experience cloud page on which I have a flow with a screen component with some input fields. I want to be able to hide 1 of these fields. I know this can be done in css with {visibility: hidden !important;} but understood its a little different in this case since the page needs to load first.
Is there a way that I can add this to the head markup?
If I do an inspect on page for the component I get the following:
<input lwc-enmikoh2qu="" class="slds-input" aria-errormessage="help-message-78" id="input-78" maxlength="255" name="Hidden_1" part="input" step="any" type="text" aria-labelledby="input-label-75">

What would the annotation be and where should I place this?

Any reason not to either just remove the input from the flow or use the screen flow's component visibility functionality to do this, rather than hack your way through it?

@PhilW I want to use the form instead of the web2case functionality since there is no attachment functionality currently out of the box and want to have hidden fields on the form so I know when bots fill the form
